# Ansible: How to set result to compliant only when all the value of found in the loop is greater than 0

Tags: loops, ansible

Here is what i am trying to do.

1. I have the debugged output of command where i am checking for specific lines in a file.
2. I have to make sure that all the recommended lines are present in the file /tmp/test.txt and even if one line is not there in the file then the result should not be set to compliant.
3. Below is the output

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "backup": "",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "found": 1,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backrefs": false,
                        "backup": false,
                        "create": false,
                        "dest": "/tmp/test.txt",
                        "firstmatch": false,
                        "group": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "black abc",
                "msg": "1 line(s) removed"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "backup": "",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "found": 1,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backrefs": false,
                        "backup": false,
                        "create": false,
                        "dest": "/tmp/test.txt",
                        "firstmatch": false,
                        "group": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "inst abc",
                "msg": "1 line(s) removed"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "backup": "",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "found": 1,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backrefs": false,
                        "backup": false,
                        "create": false,
                        "dest": "/tmp/test.txt",
                        "firstmatch": false,
                        "group": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "black efd",
                "msg": "1 line(s) removed"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "backup": "",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "found": 1,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backrefs": false,
                        "backup": false,
                        "create": false,
                        "dest": "/tmp/test.txt",
                        "firstmatch": false,
                        "group": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "inst abc",
                "msg": "1 line(s) removed"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "backup": "",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "failed_when_result": false,
                "found": 0,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backrefs": false,
                        "backup": false,
                        "create": false,
                        "dest": "/tmp/test.txt",
                        "firstmatch": false,
                        "group": null
                "item": "black xzy",
                "msg": ""
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

Here is the current play:

```yaml
- name: check config
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    line: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp/test.txt 
    state: absent
  loop: 
    - "black abc"
    - "inst abc"
    - "black efd"
    - "inst abc"
    - "black xzy"
  when: st.stat.exists == true
  register: output
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: yes
  failed_when: false

- name: "Set the result and output when compliant."
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    rule_result: "COMPLIANT"
    rule_output: "Recommended setting is configured"
  when: item.found > 0 
  loop: "{{ output.results }}"
  loop_control:
  label: "{{ item.found }}"
```

**Output of above code is COMPLIANT**

**Expected Output**:

The code should check every item.found. Even if one of the `item.found` is equal to 0 (`item.found == 0`, as in my above debugged out there is one that is set to 0), the output should not be set to Compliant.

Comment: Just wondering if [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) is not an option, because [`lineinfile` module – Manage lines in text files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#synopsis) "_is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only._"

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) is not an option, because [`lineinfile` module – Manage lines in text files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#synopsis) "*is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.*"

In any case this can become simplified much more just by checking the Common Return Values for `changed`.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - lineinfile:
      dest: test.txt
      line: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    loop: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    register: result

  - assert:
      that:
        - not result.changed
      fail_msg: "NON COMPLIANT"
      success_msg: "COMPLIANT"
```

will result into an output for the first run

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ********************
changed: [localhost] => (item=a)
changed: [localhost] => (item=b)
changed: [localhost] => (item=c)
changed: [localhost] => (item=d)
changed: [localhost] => (item=e)

TASK [assert] ************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "not result.changed",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "NON COMPLIANT"
```

and the second run

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=c)
ok: [localhost] => (item=d)
ok: [localhost] => (item=e)

TASK [assert] ************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "COMPLIANT"
```

**Documentation**

- [Common Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)
- [Defining `changed`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed)
- [`assert` module – Asserts given expressions are `true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since `found` contains what can be cast to a boolean (either 0 or a positive integer), you just need to [extract the list of `found` attributes](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) and check they are all `true` using the [`all` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true).

The following demo playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your original json data minified on a single line for legibility
    output: {"changed":false,"msg":"All items completed","results":[{"ansible_loop_var":"item","backup":"","changed":false,"failed":false,"failed_when_result":false,"found":1,"invocation":{"module_args":{"attributes":null,"backrefs":false,"backup":false,"create":false,"dest":"/tmp/test.txt","firstmatch":false,"group":null}},"item":"black abc","msg":"1 line(s) removed"},{"ansible_loop_var":"item","backup":"","changed":false,"failed":false,"failed_when_result":false,"found":1,"invocation":{"module_args":{"attributes":null,"backrefs":false,"backup":false,"create":false,"dest":"/tmp/test.txt","firstmatch":false,"group":null}},"item":"inst abc","msg":"1 line(s) removed"},{"ansible_loop_var":"item","backup":"","changed":false,"failed":false,"failed_when_result":false,"found":1,"invocation":{"module_args":{"attributes":null,"backrefs":false,"backup":false,"create":false,"dest":"/tmp/test.txt","firstmatch":false,"group":null}},"item":"black efd","msg":"1 line(s) removed"},{"ansible_loop_var":"item","backup":"","changed":false,"failed":false,"failed_when_result":false,"found":1,"invocation":{"module_args":{"attributes":null,"backrefs":false,"backup":false,"create":false,"dest":"/tmp/test.txt","firstmatch":false,"group":null}},"item":"inst abc","msg":"1 line(s) removed"},{"ansible_loop_var":"item","backup":"","changed":false,"failed":false,"failed_when_result":false,"found":0,"invocation":{"module_args":{"attributes":null,"backrefs":false,"backup":false,"create":false,"dest":"/tmp/test.txt","firstmatch":false,"group":null}},"item":"black xzy","msg":""}],"skipped":false}

  tasks:
    - name: Show if output is compliant or not
      vars:
        compliance: "{{ output.results | map(attribute='found') is all }}"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Output compliance is considered to be {{ compliance }}"
```

gives what you expect:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show if output is compliant or not] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Output compliance is considered to be False"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```